# Haskell error "Data constructor not in scope"

Tags: haskell, constructor

I have a problem with this constructor:

```
data Variables = Name Char | Value Int deriving Show 
data Tree = Empty| Node Char Tree Tree deriving Show
................
buildTree :: String -> Tree -> [Variables] -> (String,Tree,[Variables])
buildTree (x:y:z:xs) Empty v 
|isAlpha x && y == '=' = buildTree xs Empty newvar
.................
where  newvar = v ++ (Variables x (digitToInt z))
```

The error is :  Data constructor not in scope:
      Variables :: Char -> Int -> [Variables]

```
         newvar = v ++ (Variables x (digitToInt z))
```

Answer (score 3):

`Variables` is a type wich can be constructed either with `Name` holding `Char` or with `Value` holding `Int`. You probably need `Value x` to make an instance of the `Variables` type.

In addition to that, `Variables x (digitToInt z)` seems to be a nonsense according to provided definitions, since no `Variables` data constructor takes 2 parameters.